# Unable to get a Regex to process a string in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have been diligently trying to figure out how to take a working REGEX in ColdFusion, and modifying it to verify that the string does NOT INCLUDE certain characters.

The Regex in question is:

```
^[A-Z][\dA-Z]{3,3}[A-Z]${5}
```

The following are the tests I am trying to validate a string against:

1. Must be 5 digits long
2. First character MUST be an alpha
3. Last character MUST be an alpha
4. Characters 2-4 may be any combination of Alphas and Numerics
5. May not contain the letters O or I

The string I am trying to validate should have the format of:
AZZZE

So, it should pass with 
AZZZZ
A123Z

And fail with 
0A23Z
I123Z
A
A12345

It is test #5 that I simply cannot seem to get.

I have read through Adam Cameron's excellent posts on Regex and CF (http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part_22.html), where he mentions "Character set negation" as such:

> Character set negation
>   One can create a character set which indicates matching anything but what's in the character set. >this is achieved by using the ^ as a NOT operator:
>
> "c[^ie]t" will match "cat", "cot" and "cut" (and stuff like "c_t"), but will specifically not match "cit" and "cet".

So I tried some of that...

```
^(O|I)[A-Z][\dA-Z]{3,3}[A-Z]${5}
```

But now it fails test whether there's an O or an I or not.

I just can't seem to get it to fail if the string has a O or a I present.

How do I get the Regex (reFind, reFindNOCase, IsValid) to actually indicate the string is invalid if a O or I is present?

I admit, I'm very much a sophmore at this stuff.  Help!

Comment: Maybe instead of `[A-Z]` you could use `[A-H,J-N,P-Z]`.

Comment: Robert you need to do a negative lookahead to make sure the chars you don't want aren't there. I don't have time (sorry) to come up with a precise example for you just now, but there's a fairly thorough example in this article: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part_26.html.  THanks for the kind words re my blog, btw, and glad it's helped you thusfar :-)

Comment: Hey!  Adam Cameron replied to my post!  Woot Woot!!

Comment: As I showed in the OP I tried adding (^O|I) to the REGEX, but that just throws CF errors.

I tried moving it around, but simply can't determine where it should go without it throwing an error.  Not to mention, I am just probably doing it wrong.  Man... I really should do more REGEXes because they are super cool.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write:

```
^[A-HJ-NP-Z][A-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{3}[A-HJ-NP-Z]$
```

Comment: Thanks Casimir, it does work, but I am pretty sure that it can be written ... simpler.  Which is what I was trying to accomplish.

For example, I wouldn't write 0-9, I would write \d.

And I believe Adam is correct above, in that a negative look around would solve my problem.  I just can't seem to figure out the syntax yet to make that work.

Comment: @RobertBartlett: Be careful with `\d`. In several regex flavors `\d` contains not only `[0-9]` but all the digits of all languages that makes the `\d` class slower than `[0-9]`.

Comment: @RobertBartlett: using one or several lookahead at the begining of the pattern will slow down the regex engine. *(however, this technic can be handy in many cases, but its better when you can avoid it)*. Keep in mind that for each lookahead you use at the begining, the whole string is parsed once more.

Comment: Regarding the "several regex flavors", as is pointed out in the title and subsequent OP, I am only interested in a ColdFusion implementation.  I will keep your comment in mind though.

Comment: @RobertBartlett: after decoding the ColdFusion documentation. It seems to be the case. If you read carefully http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html you will notice at the last part that the class `[:digit:]` matches any unicode digits and is the "same as `\d`". But when you look upper in the same page, `\d` is only described as "similar to `[0-9]`" *(note the nuance)*. There is nothing surprising the three well know exeptions where `[0-9]` fits exactly `\d` are Java, PCRE and Javascript.

Comment: @RobertBartlett: To illustrate considerations about efficiency, you can compare these two patterns (click debugger links): http://regex101.com/r/bG5wK9/1 and http://regex101.com/r/mO9uA8/1 *(with regex, shorter isn't always better)*